# getText() from PyQt - does it have to be complex?

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm reading instructions for using PyQt, but I'm not getting the what-seems-like-basic-info that I need.

I need a widget. A basic one. All I want is to prompt the user to enter some text and to save said text as a string.

```
report_title = QInputDialog.getText(QLineEdit(), QString('Report Title:'))


TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QInputDialog.getText(QWidget, QString, QString, QLineEdit.EchoMode mode=QLineEdit.Normal, QString text=QString(), Qt.WindowFlags flags=0) -> (QString, bool): not enough arguments
  QInputDialog.getText(QWidget, QString, QString, QLineEdit.EchoMode, QString, Qt.WindowFlags, Qt.InputMethodHints) -> (QString, bool): not enough arguments
```

**EDIT** Placed Error in code block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [`getText`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qinputdialog.html#getText) shows that there are at least *three* mandatory arguments to that static methods. They are:

1. The parent widget (as usual)
2. The title of the window
3. The label, also known as, the prompt to the user. The text shown *inside* the dialog window, next to the input line edit.

For example:

```
report_title = QInputDialog.getText(someWindow, 'New report', 'Report title:')
```

You can pass plain python strings as `QString`, so there's no need to do `QString('Modify report')`

Comment: Thank you! The C++ at that documentation was really getting in the way.

Answer (score 0):

You have got some examples here: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qinputdialog.html

Altough they are in C++, it is quite similar when using Python. You need to specify more arguments when calling getText() method.

Comment: That's the other problem I'm having when I'm searching for examples...C++. I understand that I don't have enough arguments, but I don't understand what those arguments are.

Comment: You've got everything you need in the documentation.

Comment: I understand that you believe that, but I already tried reading those examples and they did me no good. I've been struggling with this for hours, and none of the examples I've found so far have shone any light on this issue.